# Java Method Character Pattern - Beginner

Tags: java, methods, user-input, user-defined-functions

I'm in my first semester of java and my dyslexia is making this extra hard, but I persist.  I need to get user input for number of rows, number of characters, and type of character.  This is for hw, so any advice is appreciated.  I need to use a method(call) to create a patter as follows with corresponding input variables and prints the total # of characters:

number of lines: 3
number of characters: 6
character: X

XXXXXX
XXXXXX
XXXXXX

total characters: 18
Here's the code I have so far:

```
static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);  
  public static void main (String[] args)  
  {  
    int totalChar;  
    int numLn = console.nextInt();          //Should I assign here or  
    int charPerLn = console.nextInt();      //after sys.println?  
    char symbol = console.next().charAt(0);  

    System.out.println("# of lines: " +numLn);

    System.out.println("# of characters: "+charPerLn);

    System.out.println("Character: "+symbol);

    System.out.print(Pattern);    //Pretty sure this is wrong or at
                                  //least in the wrong place to call

    System.out.println("Total Characters: "+totalChar);
    totalChar = numOfLines * charPerLine;
}

public static int Pattern(int x)
{
    int pattern;

    //I need a nested while or for loop here but I'm not sure how to 
    //assign the main's values for #lines and #character
    //Am I over-thinking this?  

    return pattern;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you wanted  `public static String Pattern(int numOfLines, int charPerLine, char symbol) { String pattern = ""; /* nested for loops here */; return pattern; }`   for your Pattern method. (i.e. it returns a string, and takes the three parameters that defines the pattern)

Comment: You should follow normal Java conventions. Method names should begin with a lower case letter ( so "pattern", not "Pattern"). Also, the method name should be more meaningful; in your case, perhaps "printPattern()"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);  
public static void main (String[] args)  
{  
    int totalChar;  
    int numOfLines = console.nextInt(); 
    int charPerLine = console.nextInt(); // keep your variable names consistent by using either "charPerLn" or "charPerLine", not both :)
    char symbol = console.next().charAt(0);  

    System.out.println("# of lines: " + numOfLines);
    System.out.println("# of characters: " + charPerLine);
    System.out.println("Character: " + symbol);
    System.out.println(getPattern( /* [use, the, parameters, from, above, here] */ ));

    totalChar = numOfLines * charPerLine; // first assign to totalChar, then you can print it
    System.out.println("Total Characters: " + totalChar);
}

public static String getPattern(int numOfLines, int charPerLine, char symbol) // you want to return a string, so we change "int" to "String" here
{
    String pattern = "";

    /* As "that other guy" said, nested for loops go here */
    for(/* ... */)
    {
        /* ... */
        for(/* ... */)
        {
         /* ... */
        }
        /* ... */
    }

    return pattern;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Pattern` method should resemble the following:

```
public static int Pattern(int lineCount, int charCount, char character) {

    for (int i = 0; i < lineCount; i++) {
        // Repeat the supplied character for charCount
    }
}
```

The `Pattern` method now includes parameters for the number of lines and the number of characters per line because those values will dictate how many times to iterate. I will leave the logic for printing the number of characters per line correctly to you (that would give away the entire answer), but the loop (with index `i`) iterates over the number of lines. In general, when you want to repeat something `n` times, you create a loop that has the following basic structure:

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) { /* ... */ }
```

This means that on the first iteration, `i` equals `0`, then `1`, then `2`, and so on until `i` reaches `n-1`. At that point, the iteration stops. This results in iterating `n` number of times, where `i` takes on values of `[0, 1, 2, ..., n-1]`.

The rest of the problem can be solved by applying this same principle again.